# How do I enable Intellisense sp.js in VS 2012. TILT

Tags: visual-studio, client-object-model

No matter what I try, I keep on getting the yellow triangles with the message "Intellisense was unable to colmplete an accurate...". For example when I type "SP." then among others ClientConetext does show up, but with a yellow triangle and the above message.

Googling gave me all sorts of different possible solutions but nothing works. So what do I put where exactly in my Visual Studio SprepointApp project???? 
1) Which script links do I put in the default.aspx page exactly? 
2) What exactly should be in my *reference.js file?? 

3) What exactly should be enabled in the Tools-->Options-->Text 
 Editor*>JavaScript_>Intellisense->Reference menu??

Please help me out here since this costed waaaaay to much time already...

Edit: what I have now:
In my reference file I have:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.8.2.js" />
/// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.js" />
/// <reference path="../_layouts/15/init.js" />
/// <reference path="../_layouts/15/SP.Core.js" />
/// <reference path="../_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js" />
/// <reference path="../_layouts/15/SP.UI.Dialog.js" />
/// <reference path="../_layouts/15/SP.js" />
```

Please note I have "../" instead of "~/" since the latter won't work either.

Edit2: jQuery Intellisense works fine. It's all about the SP.js intellisense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so finally I figured it out...

1) In Tools-->Options->Text Editor->Javascript-->intellisense-->references the path to my "_references.js" file in my project was missing. I added the relative path to it ("~/Script/_references.js")

2) Also the "~/_layouts/15/" part of the path's in the references.js file itself are not working for file "~/_layouts/15/sp.debug.js"(no clue why, same problem occurs in the default.aspx file, where I had to replace al the "~/" with "../". To overcome this I recreated the sp.debug.js file which I found at https://.sharepoint.com/sites/devloper/_layouts/15/sp.debug.js

3) Copeid the code and created a new sp.debug.js file and added it to the Script folder in my project in VS2012.

4) I added the following reference to my _references.js file:

```
/// <reference path="sp.debug.js" />
```

And now it works :)

Comment: Hi Tomvanderhoek, Thanks for sharing this tips. sp.debug.js did the trick for me...

Comment: Great, thank You Tom! Adding references in Options + Copying from "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.debug.js"  to local "Scripts" helped!

Answer (score 1):

try without "15" in the path

```
/// <reference path="../_layouts/init.js" />
/// <reference path="../_layouts/SP.Core.js" />
/// <reference path="../_layouts/SP.Runtime.js" />
/// <reference path="../_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js" />
/// <reference path="../_layouts/SP.js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this url having description that how to enable intellisense in VS2012
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Enable-ECMA-Client-Object-28e112cd

Comment: yas, saw that, but still not working :(. I have the _reference.js file in my project already with those lines. In fact, this is in my reference file: < /br>